# How to manage the GITkit account without an JWT idToken?

Tags: cookies, token, jwt, user-accounts, google-identity-toolkit

If I'm not supposed to keep the JWT idToken around (the "gtoken" cookie), but only use it for authentication, then how can I use the `...?mode=manageAccount` feature, which depends on the existence of idToken in the gtoken cookie?

Keep it stored on the backend and add a redirection step where I set it before redirecting to `...?mode=manageAccount` and delete it afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to keep the ID token around to maintain a session, instead you should generate a separate session ID.

The operations in manageAccount(change email, change password) require the presence of a recent ID token, so having an old, potentially expired one present wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: So you mean to say that one should force a new login with a new redirect to the management widget, where the idToken then gets deleted after the management page is left?